# OpenSSL 1.1.1 source code compilation for android platform

Tags: android, openssl, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile OpenSSL source code for android on Windows system.
I have downloaded msys, perl 5.22.1 and Setenv-android.sh
I have edited Setenv-android.sh and it is running well, but when i am running **./config shared** I am getting:

$ ./config shared

Operating system: armv7-whatever-android

Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.1 (0x1010100fL) for android-armeabi

Using os-specific seed configuration

**no NDK arm-linux-androideabi-gcc on $PATH at (eval 8) line 90.**

How can I solve **no NDK arm-linux-androideabi-gcc on $PATH at (eval 8) line 90.** problem?

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MSYS2 solved the problem!!!